# Lyx enumeration style with parentheses

Tags: lyx, enumitem

I use a module named Customisable Lists (enumitem) and I choose Insert->Enumerate Options. In ERT I write

```
label=\roman{enumi}
```

but it prints i when I would like to get i). What should I do?

Comment: Where can one find this module?

Comment: @Werner Document Settings > Modules, click on "Customizable Lists (enumitem)", then "Add". Then "OK". Then in the layout combo box, choose "Enumerate". Then Insert > Enumerate Options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `\roman*` to use the current enumeration counter, not `enumi`.

[image]

This is the output:

[image]

Note that references will match the `label` option, unless you specify it otherwise (through something like `ref=\roman*`, without the closing parenthesis `)`).